# How can I decode UTF-16 data in Perl when I don't know the byte order?

Tags: perl, decode, utf-16

If I open a file ( and specify an encoding directly ) :

```
open(my $file,"<:encoding(UTF-16)","some.file") || die "error $!\n";
while(<$file>) {
    print "$_\n";
}
close($file);
```

I can read the file contents nicely. However, if I do:

```
use Encode;

open(my $file,"some.file") || die "error $!\n";
while(<$file>) {
    print decode("UTF-16",$_);
}
close($file);
```

I get the following error:

```
UTF-16:Unrecognised BOM d at F:/Perl/lib/Encode.pm line 174
```

How can I make it work with `decode`?

EDIT: here are the first several bytes:

```
FF FE 3C 00 68 00 74 00
```

Comment: Can you show us a dump of the first several bytes of that file?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you simply specify "UTF-16", Perl is going to look for the byte-order mark (BOM) to figure out how to parse it. If there is no BOM, it's going to blow up. In that case, you have to tell Encode which byte-order you have by specifying either "UTF-16LE" for little-endian or "UTF-16BE" for big-endian.

There's something else going on with your situation though, but it's hard to tell without seeing the data you have in the file. I get the same error with both snippets. If I don't have a BOM and I don't specify a byte order, my Perl complains either way. Which Perl are you using and which platform do you have? Does your platform have the native endianness of your file? I think the behaviour I see is correct according to the docs.

Also, you can't simply read a line in some unknown encoding (whatever Perl's default is) then ship that off to `decode`. You might end up in the middle of a multi-byte sequence. You have to use `Encode::FB_QUIET` to save the part of the buffer that you couldn't decode and add that to the next chunk of data:

```
open my($lefh), '<:raw', 'text-utf16.txt';

my $string;
while( $string .= <$lefh> ) {
    print decode("UTF-16LE", $string, Encode::FB_QUIET) 
    }
```

Comment: You know, if I concatenate the strings into one large buffer, I can use decode on it succesfully.

Comment: You can decode the whole thing at once because it sees the BOM for the whole string. Breaking it up into individual lines means the BOM is only for the first chunk. Encode doesn't do anything special to try to guess that one string is somehow related to another.

Answer (score 6):

You need to specify either UTF-16BE or UTF-16LE. See http://perldoc.perl.org/Encode/Unicode.html#Size%2c-Endianness%2c-and-BOM

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do impossible.

You're reading *lines* of text without specifying an encoding, so every byte that contains a newline character (default `\x0a`) ends a line.  But this newline character may very well be in the middle of an UTF-16 character, in which case your next line can't be decoded.
If your data is UTF-16LE, this will happen all the time – line feeds are `\x0a \x00`.  If you have UTF16-BE, you might get lucky (newlines are `\x00 \x0a`), until you get a character with `\x0a` in the high byte.

So, don't do that, open the file in the right encoding.

Comment: What if you don't always have a file, and you only get passed a string?

Comment: It's not impossible: see my answer for how you should handle incomplete byte sequences.